# Is it possible somehow to animate several Qt effects without timer?

Tags: python, qt, animation, pyqt

I'd like to make the animation with built-in Qt effects, e.g. simultaneous disappearing and blurring of text, but unfortunatelly it is possible to assign only one effect to an object.. and then you have to make it all by your hands and timers.. I wonder is there any way to make animation of several effects with one widget?

As an example:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

win = QtGui.QMainWindow()
lbl = QtGui.QLabel()
win.setCentralWidget(lbl)

lbl.setFont(QtGui.QFont('Arial', 100))
lbl.setText('Hello, World!')

win.show()

effect1 = QtGui.QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
effect2 = QtGui.QGraphicsBlurEffect()  # <- how to attach this one also?
lbl.setGraphicsEffect(effect1)

anim = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(effect1, 'opacity')
anim.setDuration(1000)
anim.setStartValue(1)
anim.setEndValue(0)
anim.start()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to make the animation with built-in Qt effects, e.g.
>   simultaneous disappearing and blurring of text, but unfortunatelly it
>   is possible to assign only one effect to an object.. and then you have
>   to make it all by your hands and timers.. I wonder is there any way to
>   make animation of several effects with one widget?

The modern technique would be QML: [Usecase - Animations In QML](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-usecase-animations.html). There is a number of [blur](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=qml%20blur) effects available. And with QML we program the transition between states of QML objects: in our case less blurred and more blurred or maybe vice versa. As for doing QML with Python, I am unsure but even without C++ you can create the application with just declarative QML and JavaScript. And it seems even with Python some techniques to make it work with QML [available](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=qml%20python).